# Is there any difference between 重大 VS 重点 (used as adj.)?

Tags: difference

Is there any difference between 重大 VS 重点 when they are used as adjective? Or is it just a thing to remember: this time use 重大 and that time use 重点:

> 重大事件 (and 重点事件?)
>
> 重大进展 (and 重点进展?)
>
> 重点工程 (and 重大工程? - this version sounds correct, but still is there any difference?)
>
> 重点扶持 (and 重大扶持?)

Comment: one is an adjective the other is a noun
bkrs： **重大**    great; weighty; major; significant; important; grave; serious:
重大消息 grave news
具有重大意义 be of great (immense) significance
取得重大进展 make significant progress (headway)
重大的原则分歧 a major difference of principle
   **重点**  keynote; key point; focal point; stress; emphasis:
阐明重点 elucidate a point of importance
发展战略的重点 priority in our development strategy
工作重点 focal point of the work
突出重点 make the focal (key) points stand out
争夺重点 cockpit; focus of contention (rivalry)
把重点放在疾病的预防上 lay (put; place) stress on (upon) ...

Comment: find examples for   **重点**   used  **attributively**   (jukuu down!) at ichacha:重点班 tracked class for bright students; 重点产品 major products; 重点抽样 importance sampling; 重点大学 key university [college]; major university; 重点单位 key unit; 重点调查 key-point investigation; 重点访问 focused interview; 重点高等院校 key institutes of higher learning;

Answer (score 2):

重大 means "important (adj) / serious (adj)"

重点 means "focused (adj)/ focal point (n)"

Important thing might not be focused at the moment; focused thing at the moment might not be very important in the grand scheme of things

For example, stopping gun violence is an important issue, but Americans just don't focus on it at the moment; On the other hand, American is focus on the issue of 'should the football players kneel during the national anthem.' It is not an important issue compare to other real issues, but it is the focal point at the moment nonetheless.

> 重大事件 (and 重点事件?)
>
> 重大进展 (and 重点进展?)
>
> 重点工程 (and 重大工程? - this version sounds correct, but still is there any difference?)
>
> 重点扶持 (and 重大扶持?)

- 重大事件 (serious incident) and 重大进展 (important development) are valid
- 重点事件 (focused incident) and 重点进展 (focused development) are not valid
- 重点工程 (focused project)  and 重大工程 (important project) are valid.
- 重点扶持 (focused support) is valid;  重大扶持 (serious support) is not valid

Answer (score 2):

"重大" means somehow generally important or big. -- It is generally speaking. While "重点" means we put emphasis on this point or we focus on this point, as compared to other, less emphatic points.

For example, if we build 10 high buildings in an area, they can all be " big constructions" so they are all "重大工程".

But maybe one of them is built for hospital or school, compared to others, this is the really really important one, then this is a "重点工程".

Answer (score 2):

重点: noun or attributive noun, means **key or key point**. For example, 工作重点: key point of the work; 重点工程： the key projects;

重大：adjective, means **extraordinary big**, and extraordinary big things are also important things. For example, 重大工程：important and big projects; 重大事件：important and big affairs;

Now, you should know the difference between 重大工程 and 重点工程. It's like "Key projects" vs "important and big projects". Sometimes, they could be overlapped because those key projects could be those important and big projects.